# Minimalist Ubuntu System

Tags: command-line, apt

I use Ubuntu mini.iso to install minimalist system deselecting all software options, then after reboot install xorg, display manager (slim) and LXDE. Is there a difference in the amount of installed packages when the install command has a different order, such as:

```
sudo apt --no-install-recommends install xorg slim lxde
sudo apt install xorg slim lxde --no-install-recommends
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends xorg slim lxde
```

If there is a difference, which command variant installs the least amount of packages?

Comment: You've provided no release details; and the commands may have different requirements for different releases (in fact I'd expect that, esp. for more modern releases given LXDE hasn't been a Lubuntu package for numerous release).  The `mini.iso` is no longer produced either; as it was a by-product of a no-longer used procedure (it was never fully supported by Ubuntu or Canonical).  See "*Future of MinimialCD*" at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: To answer your question, NO, changing the order in which they appear in the command will not have any impact IF the packages are the same & release details are the same.

Comment: I think you should use Science to answer this: Spin up a virtual machine, try one permutation of commands, measure and record the results. Rinse and repeat for each permutation. Then you tell us the conclusive, reproducible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of non-option and option arguments do not matter, except for options that conflict with each other (e.g., `apt ... --no-install-recommends ... --install-recommends ...` and `apt ... --install-recommends ... --no-install-recommends` will have different behaviour). You can test this out easily for yourself by tacking on a `--simulate` to each of these commands:

```
# sudo apt --no-install-recommends install xorg slim lxde --simulate  | grep -w and

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

0 upgraded, 335 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

# sudo apt install xorg slim lxde --no-install-recommends --simulate  | grep -w and

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

0 upgraded, 335 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

# sudo apt install --no-install-recommends xorg slim lxde --simulate  | grep -w and

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

0 upgraded, 335 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! Something I'd like to clarify: I see that often apt-get is used instead of apt, however apt is newer and better than apt-get. What would be the reason to use apt-get?

Answer (score 4):

You've provided no release details; and the commands may have different requirements if different releases are involved  (*in fact I'd expect that, esp. for more modern releases given LXDE hasn't been a Lubuntu package for numerous release; it's now purely Debian packages*).

The `mini.iso` is no longer produced either; as it was a by-product of a no-longer used procedure (it was never fully supported by Ubuntu or Canonical).  See "*Future of MinimialCD*" at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

> Canonical and the Ubuntu project never officially supported the
> mini.iso ; it was produced as a by-product of building the
> debian-installer. As the Ubuntu Server image now uses subiquity, the
> build process that built mini.iso is no longer used, thus why this
> installation media is now old.

To answer your question, **NO**, changing the order in which they appear in the command will not have any impact *IF* the packages are the same & release details are the same; as you appear to have the same command with just a different order of operands.

Differences in `apt` may need to be taken into account as no release is provided, so this advice is generic & assumes my current release.

Comment: Shame I can only award one chevron to this answer, so here are two thumbs 

Comment: The release is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. The "mini.iso" I used is here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso

Comment: @Zen99  fyi:  that's not Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS media as that was created using only `subiquity` .. you've got 20.04 or the initial release of 20.04 (2020-April not 2021-Feb; see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/ for date of ISO release for 20.04.2).  It won't make a lot of difference, as if it installs you can upgrade packages; but it's still not got upgraded security patches required to boot on some hardware (*thus it may or may not boot on all devices*)

Comment: Thank you. Ubuntu is not the right distro for minimalist system, so I installed Devuan from the "devuan_chimaera_4.0.0_amd64_netinstall.iso". With fully functional LXDE desktop and all software installed it took 2.9 GB of disk space and 169 MB RAM on boot. It looks like no "systemd" makes a difference, since the same type of installation from the "debian-11.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso" uses more disk space and 212 MB RAM on boot. Devuan based Star Linux is even lighter with only 129 MB RAM on boot. I completely agree with Distrowatch ratings: Star 9.3 - Devuan 9.2 - Debian 8.8 - Ubuntu 7.6.